# How to store values of database in array and than how to get the last inserted record from that array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have made an iphone application like flip cards in which values of cards come from database randomly. I have made the functionality to go to the next card on clicking "Next" button. Again random card values comes from the database randomly.

I have used code as -

```
//On ViewDidLoad()

[self databaseOpen];

    NSString *query_wordData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from tbl_flashcards order by random() limit 1"];
    NSArray *wordData = [database executeQuery:query_wordData];
    NSLog(@"WORD DATA : %@",wordData);

    NSString *str = [[wordData objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Term"];
    NSString *str1 = [[wordData objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Definition"];

    [btnBackCard  setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnFrontCard setTitle:str1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [database close];
    [database release];

//on Next button

    -(IBAction) nextButtonPressed
{
   isBack = YES;

    btnFrontCard.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    [self frontButtonAnimation];


}
```

Now i want to implement the "Back" button functionality in which the cards which are shown just can be shown again in "last shown card show first" manner.

I know i have to store those last accessed cards in an array and than call last indexed card from that array on "Back" button clicking.But i dont know how to  do this.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Your NSArray *wordData contains all data, right?

Comment: @NuzhatZari - ya *wordData contains all data(i.e 1 row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't limit your query by using `limit 1`. Retrieve all cards in random order (by omitting the limit in your query) and use an index on the array to switch back and forth between the cards as you pressed the button respectively

**EDIT :**

Define your array as a member of your view controller. Than when initializing the controller use this member to receive the records from the db and use it wherever you need in your controller's methods.

Comment: I want to implement BACK button functionality in which cards which are just shown can be again show as last index first manner.

Comment: So retrieve all card records in a random order (without using limit) and use a member variable index (initialize with 0) to get it from the array. Increase the index when pressing next. decrease it when pressing back.

Comment: i have tried the solution that you have suggested. But at NEXT button click, i cant be able to access that array.

Comment: I added explanation for this. I assume you know how to declare members and how to use them. if not let me know ...